# Filling out and submitting a form for a newly opened window

Tags: javascript

What I'd like to do is open a new window, then submit the form in that new window after automatically filling out he form elements from the original window. Here is what I tried to do:

```
var username = 'myuser';
var password = 'mypass';
var loginWindow = window.open('http://www.mysite.com/form.html', 'loginWindow');
loginWindow.document.getElementById('username').value=username;
loginWindow.document.getElementById('password').value=password;
loginWindow.document.form.submit();
```

This however does not work, and instead gives me the following error: "Result of expression 'loginWindow.document' [undefined] is not an object."

Is this even possible? Can jQuery solve this?

Comment: you are missing a ' after the url in the open function.

Comment: good point, fixed. that wasn't it though :(

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error, it works as expected when I run it in Firefox, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm trying it in both Safari and Firefox. What does work is the opening of the window. What doesn't work is the submitting of the form with the new values. Are you seeing that work on your end?

Comment: You will not be permitted to refer to objects in a document hosted on a different server to the one the current document was retrieved from. Are both documents on the same server? Are you using the 'www' prefix for one but not the other?

Comment: ooooh, interesting. I'm indeed loading a page on a completely different domain. Didn't think about the XSS issues here. Can you post that as an answer (and maybe some suggestions to work around)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be permitted to refer to objects in a document hosted on a different domain to the one the current document was retrieved from. Are both documents in the same domain? Are you using the 'www' prefix for one but not the other?

If you have to pass information across domains, consider passing it via the URL. Alternatively, is there any reason not to submit the data yourself directly to the location the target form would be submitting it to?